# Iterating over rows of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm am iterating over dynamically generated div which contains a table. While I'm iterating over rows, Suppose I'm having two rows, I'm getting two results. But the problem is that both the results contain values of last row of table. Here is my code:

```
$(this)
  .children('.js-charge-data')
  .children('.js-charging-line-wrapper')
  .find('.js-chargeline-tbody')
  .children('tr')
  .each(function() {
    chargingLineJSON['chargingType'] = 'IoT';
    chargingLineJSON['chargeCategoryName'] = $(this).find('.js-charging-category').val().trim();
    chargingLineJSON['subCategoryName'] = $(this).find('.js-charging-sub-category').val().trim();
    chargingLineJSON['backEndProductName'] = $(this).find('.js-charging-sub-category').children(':selected').data('backend_product_name');
    chargingLineJSON['shipToAddressId'] = '123';
    chargingLineJSON['chargePerUnit'] = $(this).find('.js-unit-charge').val().trim();

    chargeLineListJSON['chargingLine'] = chargingLineJSON;
    chargingLineJSONArray.push(chargeLineListJSON);
  });
```

Please let me know what mistake am I doing?

Comment: Please include all relevant code (html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing same object `chargingLineJSON` to the array, Create a new object in the `.each()` block

```
.each(function () {
    //Create a new object
    var chargingLineJSON = {};
    //Your code
    chargingLineJSONArray.push(chargeLineListJSON);
});
```

As per [@Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) comment

Objects are copied using reference. So in second iteration, when you set value to object's property, you are overriding value at a memory location and not in a locat variable. Hence, same values

Answer (score 1):

As commented and credited in [@Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953772/3783478), issue is due to object copied as a reference.

Not repeating the comment in my answer though to reduce duplication of data.

You can use something like this.

```js
$(this)
  .find('.js-charge-data .js-charging-line-wrapper .js-chargeline-tbody tr')
  .each(function() {
    let category = $(this).find('.js-charging-category');
    let subCategory = $(this).find('.js-charging-sub-category');
    let selectedSubCategory = $(this).find('.js-charging-sub-category :selected');
    let unitCharge =  $(this).find('.js-unit-charge');

    chargingLineJSONArray.push({
      chargingType: 'IoT',
      shipToAddressId: '123'
      chargeCategoryName: category.val().trim(),
      subCategoryName: subCategory.val().trim(),
      backEndProductName: selectedSubCategory.data('backend_product_name'),
      chargePerUnit: unitCharge.val().trim()
    });

    // Not sure what this line is about? 
    // You are saving reference to self in a property.
    // chargeLineListJSON['chargingLine'] = chargingLineJSON;
  });
```

**Note:** I have not tested code as mark is missing.